# Azure Resources WebApp deployed but not accessible from url

Tags: azure, azure-devops, web-deployment

I'm trying to access my app, hosted on azure.
I've a finished c# solution. When I commit changes to Azure DevOps it triggers a (working & successful) build-pipeline.
It runs tests, publishes an artifact & testresults.

[image]

In my ServicePlan status is Ready and I see Data Exchanges on DataIn & DataOut graphs.

[image]

The Deployment Center:
[image: Deployment Center]

[image]

Bu when I click the https://mywebsite.azurewebsites.net, No webpage was found for the web address.

I have Some basic Azure DevOps expierence, but this Azure Portal is something else :)

My basic questions would be:
Why is it not working?

Do I need a second pipeline, only for release? Or can I recycle the build pipeline?

Do I need some kind of deployment slots? Before I select a not-free slot, I want to know if this is necessary

What else could I be missing?
(My Azure resources include a sql-server, a sql-db, the actual appservice & a app service plan)

Thanks!

Comment: In Azure DevOps you will need to setup a build pipeline and a release pipeline. This is a lengthy topic and probably not suitable to this forum.

Comment: @Kane, thanks for the answer. I can set up a release pipeline I guess. Will do some research on what makes it different from build pipeline. I noticed it's quite a big topic (:o) but you gave me a good lead! Thanks again

Comment: @Kane still have some troubles, do you know a forum where this topic is suitable? I've followed micrsoft tutorial, pluralsight and an old school course. But all sources are outdated or not applicable to my issue it seems..

Comment: Hi @BHANG, You can free free  to share your questions in the SO and add related tags, better for specific problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you deploy web app to Azure and login `https://<app-name>.azurewebsites.net`, then the page still shows Microsoft page instead you owner page. You need check the default document, please ensure that the default page is listed in here.

Steps: login azure portal->App Service->configuration->Default documents

In Azure Web Apps, the default document is the web page that is displayed at the root URL for a website. The first matching file in the list is used. Refer [File structure on azure](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/File-structure-on-azure) to know more about the files and directories on Azure Web App.

**Update1**

> When I go to the azurewebsites.net url I get a 404: No webpage was found for the web address.

Check this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain#resolve-404-not-found):

If you receive an HTTP 404 (Not Found) error when you browse to the URL of your custom domain, verify that your domain resolves to your app's IP address by using WhatsmyDNS.net. If not, it might be because of one of the following reasons:

- The custom domain configured is missing an A record or a CNAME
  record.
- The browser client has cached the old IP address of your domain.
  Clear the cache, and test DNS resolution again. On a Windows machine,
  you clear the cache with ipconfig /flushdns.

**Update2**

> the URL in my appservice is Azure-generated right?

Yes, then app service url is generated by Azure.

> With making a new app service and going to the URL I do get a message app service is up and running.Time to take the next step and deploy your code.

And now, we should get this page, we need create new service connection and re-configure build and release pipeline and deploy your app.

[image]

Note: We need use the same user account and AAD domain to do this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My default document is index.html. When I go to the azurewebsites.net url I get a 404: No webpage was found for the web address.
I have a working release pipeline (that takes an artifact from a build pipeline). If I ng build --prod in angular, build succeeds. But when I ng run <projectname>:deploy I get: Project target does not exist. I've tried fondling with the inner workings of angular-devkit architect to get a more elaborate error message but somehow my changes don't even get implemented.

Comment: Hi @BHANG, check the update1 and kindly share the result here. In addition, you could also check this [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55658948/asp-net-core-api-get-404-on-azure-app-service-but-works-ok-on-localhost)

Comment: Thank you for the update! ATM I'm not working with custom domains. Have flushed DNS. When I want to deploy from AngularCLI I still get Unhandled Exception: Project target does not exist. If I try to access my azurewebsites.net through azurePortal I still get the 404

Comment: Hi @BHANG, could you log in azure portal and open app service to check if URL is correct? When we create app service in the azure portal, we could see the URL link in the app service summary page. Please create a new app service and try it again.

Comment: When I try to log in he says he can't find my account, but when I want to login with a different account, he says he can't because I'm logged in with the account he can't find. When I eventually get into my account, I cannot add new subscriptions because 'I entered the wrong validation code' when I want to register my payment.... (tried this 12 times) . The URL in my appservice is Azure-generated right? I would assume it is correct.. With making a new app service and going to the URL I do get a message app service is up and running.Time to take the next step and deploy your code.

Comment: Hi @BHANG, I have updated my answer, check the update2.

Comment: Thankyou @Vito. I've added a service connection and looking into buildconfig. ATM I have a Azure App Service Deployment Error: There is not enough space on the disk. Will investigate and create a new ticket if needed. Thanks for your help. For other readers: It can take some time & a couple of logout/logins before subscriptions, plans etc get displayed & connected correctly.